# Unable to commit local changes after reset

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-rebase, git-reset

I am trying to commit my local changes, but they are not seen by git (git status shows no changes). This happend after I cancelled my last commit using `git reset HEAD~1`, because I forgot to rebase the master branch. How can I make these changes visible? Git treats them as they were a part of a previous snapshot, hence the inability to commit them. Note that the master still has previous unchanged version a file.

Comment: I usually add a minor change like a new space or small string of code and then try again

Comment: I tried to do this, but it still does not recognize actually relevant changes.

Comment: _Git treats them as they were a part of a previous snapshot, hence the inability to commit them._

They might be? Look at the history using `gitk` or similar.

`git reset HEAD~1` should have left any changes between `HEAD` and `HEAD~1` as staged changes. Are you sure changes were made between those two commits? Do you need to go back further.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, nobody else was working on this file.

Comment: @Adam thanks actually for introducing me to `gitk` command, thanks to that I managed to restore the previous state of the file.